# Not able to install logstash plugins in a linux server : Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: plugins, rubygems, logstash, logstash-filter

i am trying to install logstash plugin "logstash-filter-environment" in a linux server with the command "sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-environment".

Got this error "Validating logstash-filter-environment
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org - Received fatal alert: handshake_failure (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR: Installation aborted, verification failed for logstash-filter-environment".

Tried these commands but no use:
sudo gem sources -r https://rubygems.org,
sudo gem sources -a http://rubygems.org

Please help if you know this issue, appreciate your time.

Comment: I was running into this issue with the logstash-input-beats plugin. I did not solve the ssl issue as I found out the plugin I wanted was already bundled with logstash v5.0.1. But I was reading that maybe your firewall is blocking it. And if not then you can always try an offline install https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/offline-plugins.html